# ContextualVersionConflict error message when using "web3" on google colab

Tags: python, protocol-buffers, google-colaboratory, web3py

```
pip install protobuf==4.21.6
```

Successfully installed protobuf-4.21.6

```
pip install web3
```

Successfully installed

```
pip freeze | grep protobuf

protobuf==4.21.6

from web3 import Web3
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ContextualVersionConflict                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-3fb76b1c6e0c> in <module>
----> 1 from web3 import Web3
      2 
      3 web3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider("https://bsc-dataseed.binance.org/"))
      4 isConnected = web3.isConnected()
      5 

5 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py in _resolve_dist(self, req, best, replace_conflicting, env, installer, required_by, to_activate)
    871             # Oops, the "best" so far conflicts with a dependency
    872             dependent_req = required_by[req]
--> 873             raise VersionConflict(dist, req).with_context(dependent_req)
    874         return dist
    875 

ContextualVersionConflict: (protobuf 3.19.6 (/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages), Requirement.parse('protobuf>=4.21.6'), {'web3'})
```

Looking in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages, I can see 4.21.6

what Can I do?

I want to use web3 normally.